# PostgreSQL exponentially weighted moving average

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, function, stored-procedures

As stated in this blog post,

https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/knowledge/trading-investing/exponentially-weighted-moving-average-ewma/

It looks like you can calculate a EWMA. Now there are some ways that have been published but an alternative way has been suggested by David G Johnson in the Postgres Slack channel.

```sql
create or replace function wavg(inputs float8[]) returns float8
language sql as  
$$ select sum(c*(.133)*(.133^(i-1)))
from unnest(inputs) 
with ordinality as vals (c, i);
$$;
```

```sql
select array_agg(v) over (order by i desc rows between 13 preceding and current row) as input,
wavg(array_agg(v) over (order by i desc rows between 13 preceding and current row)) from
(values (1,119.06),(2,119.86),(3,127.19),(4,125.04),(5,124.26),(6,125.17),
(7,127.71),(8,131.11),(9,134.10),(10,133.43),(11,131.28),(12,134.56),
(13,133.77),(14,133.61)) vals (i,v) order by i asc;  -- answer is 129.34

select array_agg(v) over (order by i desc rows between 13 preceding and current row) as input,
wavg(array_agg(v) over (order by i desc rows between 13 preceding and current row)) from
(values (1,130.88),(2,129.18),(3,127.15),(4,128.25),(5,128.54),(6,128.08),
(7,129.12),(8,129.22),(9,130.79),(10,132.04),(11,131.81),(12,132.34),
(13,131.64),(14,132.48)) vals (i,v) order by i asc;  -- answer is 132.00
```

Since the results are not close to the wildly accepted answer, I am looking for the error in the above algorithm. I suspect the weights should total to one for all of the inputs but they don't. Seems like a very low code way to do this if we can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that the weights do not add up to 1.  Here is a fix for that (along with a trivial bit of cleanup).

```
create or replace function wavg(inputs float8[]) returns float8
language sql as  
$$ select sum(c*(.133)^i)) / sum(.133^i)
from unnest(inputs) 
with ordinality as vals (c, i);
$$;
```

And if you wanted a time series of weighted moving averages, you could use the same idea but with [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)

Comment: I don't see anything that looks like it is an answer to the calculation? Does seem to balance the weights.